# Ограничение на количество запросов в секунду

Tags: c#

Я постоянно опрашиваю сервер по API. Разрешено опрашивать 20раз/сек и 1200раз/мин
Подскажите как мне программно задать программе, что бы она не выходила за эти пределы? можно ссылкой на статью или книгу

Делаю так

```
while(true)
{
//разные запросы (1-5шт) в зависимости от условия

//и тут надо добавить как-то проверку на лимиты
}
```

P.S. Делать длинные паузы не желательно, тк важна каждая мс.

Comment: Подсчитывайте сколько отправили за последнюю секунду/минуту и при достижении порога ожидайте с помощью `Task.Delay` нужное время

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim`+`async/await`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Посчитайте время выделенное на 1 запрос (в вашем условии - 50 мсек)
2. Запишите текущее время перед выполнением запроса
3. Выполните запрос
4. Перед стартом нового запроса "засните" на `50 мсек - (текущее время - предыдущее время)`.
5. Повторите с шага 2.

Итого вы будете выполнять по запросу не чаще чем раз в 50 мсек.

P.S. Используйте высокоточное время. Не знаю как в C#, но в Delphi, к примеру, стандартная точность таймера `GetTickCount` около 16мсек, и поднимается до 1мсек вызовом   `TimeBeginPeriod(1)`.

Comment: делать 50мс до/после запроса, не надо, время играет очень большую роль. Надо что бы как то после всех методов он просчитаывал

Comment: Запрос времени никак вас не замедлит. Не понял ваш комментарий, уточните в вопросе плиз. Может быть приложите диаграмму по времени как должно быть (насколько параллелится/асинхронится все?)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать лимит на 20 запросов/сек. и при этом не ограничивать каждый запрос в рамках 50 мс, используем следующий класс:

```
class RequestLimiter
{
    //Здесь хранятся экспирации лимитов для последних запросов
    Queue<DateTime> Expirations = new Queue<DateTime>(20);

    public void EnsureAllowed()
    {
        //Здесь мы забываем инфу о слишком давних запросах
        while (Expirations.Count > 0 && Expirations.Peek() < DateTime.Now)
        {
            Expirations.Dequeue(); //Сложность О(1)
        }

        //Здесь мы проверяем есть ли место для очередного запроса
        if (Expirations.Count < 20)
        {
            Expirations.Enqueue(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1));
        }
        //Если нет, то спим, пока не пройдет секунда с момента самого давнего запроса
        else 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Expirations.Peek() - DateTime.Now);
            EnsureAllowed();
        }
    }
}
```

И будем вызывать метод `EnsureAllowed()` перед каждым запросом. Например, так:

```
var limiter = new RequestLimiter();
while(true)
{       
    limiter.EnsureAllowed();
    Request();
    /*...*/
    limiter.EnsureAllowed();
    Request();
}
```

Все просто. **Но хотелось бы  добавить**, что вы можете попасть в ситуацию, когда 20 запросов выполнятся за первые 20 мс и вы уйдете в аут на 980 мс. Иногда это намного хуже, чем равномерно делать 1 запрос раз в 50 мс. Иногда.